# Is there any way I can get who gave the role to the log system I'm doing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I was wanting to make a logging system for roles for my roleplay server but I need to make the bot get the name of who gave the role to that person.

```js
client.on("guildMemberUpdate", (oldMember, newMember) => {
    // Old roles Collection is higher in size than the new one. A role has been removed.
    if (oldMember.roles.cache.size > newMember.roles.cache.size) {
        // Creating an embed message.
        const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
        Embed.setColor("RED");
        Embed.setAuthor(newMember.user.tag, newMember.user.avatarURL());
        
        // Looping through the role and checking which role was removed.
        oldMember.roles.cache.forEach(role => {
            if (!newMember.roles.cache.has(role.id)) {
                Embed.addField("Role Removed", role);
            }
        });

        client.channels.cache.get("872558074290896908").send(Embed);
    } else if (oldMember.roles.cache.size < newMember.roles.cache.size) {
        const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
        Embed.setColor("GREEN");
        Embed.setAuthor(newMember.user.tag, newMember.user.avatarURL());
        
        // Looping through the role and checking which role was added.
        newMember.roles.cache.forEach(role => {
            if (!oldMember.roles.cache.has(role.id)) {
                Embed.addField("Role Added", role);
            }
        });
        client.channels.cache.get("872558074290896908").send(Embed);
    }
});
```

Comment: You need to read the [audit logs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildAuditLogs) for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you will need to use audit logs as it isn't included in the arguments provided with the event. Working with audit logs can be a bit difficult but the documentation has some great resources like this one to help you get started: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/audit-logs.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.